# Title: How to fit a Frequentist Equivalent of Bayesian mixed-effects model with nlme or lme4 and obtain category-specific variances and intercepts?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, brms, rstan

I am interested in fitting a Bayesian mixed-effects model to my data using the brms package. My data includes three grouping variables (Category, BioRep, and TechRep), and I want to estimate category-specific variances and intercepts. I have already generated simulated data and fit a model with the following code:

```
library(brms)
library(tidyverse)

# set up parameters
n_categories <- 100
n_tech_reps <- 5
n_bio_reps <- 5
higher_var_categories <- sample(1:n_categories, size = floor(n_categories/3))
batch_effect_scale <- 0.1
cat_sigmas <- rnorm(n_categories, mean = 2, sd = 0.5)
cat_sigmas[higher_var_categories] <- rnorm(length(higher_var_categories), mean = 4, sd = 1)

# generate simulated data
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:n_categories) {
  category_mean <- rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 2)
  category_var <- cat_sigmas[i]
  for (j in 1:n_bio_reps) {
    bio_effect <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = batch_effect_scale)
    for (k in 1:n_tech_reps) {
      tech_effect <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = batch_effect_scale)
      value <- rnorm(1, mean = category_mean + bio_effect + tech_effect, sd = category_var)
      data <- rbind(data, data.frame(Category = i, BioRep = j, TechRep = k, Value = value))
    }
  }
}

# modify brmsformula to include category-specific sigma
brmsformula <- bf(Value ~ 1 + (1|Category) + (1|BioRep) + (1|TechRep), 
                   sigma ~ 1 + (1 | Category))

# fit model with modified formula
model <- brm(brmsformula, data = data, chains = 4, cores = 4, 
             control = list(adapt_delta = 0.99, max_treedepth = 15))

summary(model)
# BiocManager::install("broom.mixed")
library(broom.mixed)

# extract parameter estimates and credible intervals
params <- tidy(model,conf.int = TRUE)
ranef(model)

est_cat_sigmas <- ranef(model)$Category[,'Estimate','sigma_Intercept']

# plot category-specific sigmas
cor.test(est_cat_sigmas, cat_sigmas)
```

This works great but I can't figure out how to generate the frequentist equivalent (if such exists??) for comparison.

My best attempt:

```
# fit mixed-effects model with category-specific variances
# fit mixed-effects model with category-specific variances
mixedmodel <- nlme(model=Value ~ Category + (1 | BioRep) + (1 | TechRep), 
                    fixed = Category ~ 1,
                   groups = BioRep+TechRep~1,
                   data = data, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Category),
                   start = list(
                    fixed = list(Category = rep(0, n_categories)),
                    random = list(
                        BioRep = matrix(rep(0, n_bio_reps)),
                        TechRep = matrix(rep(0, n_tech_reps))
                        )
                   )
                   )
```

Is telling me that he grouping formula is wrong. (I also think the start parameter here could be wrong).

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would be the frequentist equivalent. I couldn't get it to converge with your data, but I think this is the analogue to the brms model.

```
m <- lme(Value ~ 1, 
         random = list(~ 1|Category, ~ 1|BioRep, ~1|TechRep), 
         weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|Category),
         data = data)
```

I don't think you need to use `nlme()`. That's for non-linear mixed effect models. Also it appears you're using lme4 syntax with nlme functions. With the nlme package, random effects need to be specified using the random argument.

Comment: This is already helpful, thanks! It's weird to me that it wouldn't converge even on toy data like this - the lm call works fine, so it's not like the parameters aren't identified..

Comment: Removing the weights line makes it converge, so my guess is that the problem is the overall sigma and the category specific sigmas are underdetermined, and you need to specify one of those category sigmas or 0, say, to make this work.

Comment: See solution above, just needed to fiddle with the optimizer parameters!